# Simplify OR and AND on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I simplify this function, to not be repetitive:

```
If [F11] = "" Or [F12] = "" Or [F13] = "" Or [F14] = "" Or [F15] = "" Or [F16] = "" Or [F17] = "" Or [F18] = "" Or [F19] = "" Or [F20] = "" Or [F21] = "" Then [...]
```

Comment: If you need to determine if a value exists in a range of cells, you can use a simple formula based on the `COUNTIF` function. Example `=COUNTIF(range,value)>0`

Comment: `If Application.countblank([F16:F21]) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if any blank cell exist in your range.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MyAnswer()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("F10:F100")
    If rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells.Count = 0 Then
        ' Stuff you need
    EndIf

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the range and break if any cell is `""`

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestBlanks

    Dim rngData As Range, rngCell As Range, blnRangeHasBlanks As Boolean

    ' assume no blanks
    blnRangeHasBlanks = False

    ' iterate range and break on any blank
    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F11:F21")
    For Each rngCell In rngData
        If rngCell.Value = "" Then
            blnRangeHasBlanks = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next For

    If blnRangeHasBlanks Then
        ' ... do what you need
    End If

End Sub
```